# Why i can't install from Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 12.04, installation, software-center

Hy , Please why i can't install software from Ubuntu Software Center ? No install button !

[image]

Comment: Are you using any proxy?

Comment: How long has it been since you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you using another program to update/upgrade/install something else? If so, wait them to finish, then try again.

Comment: @souravc no proxy

Comment: @KI4JGT : i just installed it

Comment: Why did you only post a cropped screen shot? For all we know, the answer could be right there on the other part of the `software-center` application. You need to show the whole application in the screen shot, and please specify the exact package you are trying to install, in your question.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu : yes i already used update and upgrade but now it's finished

Comment: @SMAOUH Ok, if is finished, restart Ubuntu Softer Center and install what you wish. The lock should should be gone...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have by any chance have you removed Network-Manager from your Ubuntu distribution?
If the network-manager is removed from your Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine then it is more than likely the install button will be 'greyed out'.

You will still be able to install applications through the terminal. But overall the network-manager will have to be re-installed if you un-installed it.

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and submit the command `sudo apt-get install network-manager network-manager-gnome`.